# React element onClick not fires on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, mobile, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm developing a wordpress plugin with react, but the following onClick event does not fire on mobile devices (tested on Android and Ios too)

```
<button
  id={`in${this.props.wpObject.invoiceitemid}`}
  style={{
    cursor: "pointer",
  }}
  onClick={(event) =>
    this.increment(
      this.props.wpObject.eventid,
      this.props.wpObject.invoiceitemid,
      event
    )
  }
>
  {this.props.wpObject.buttontext}
</button>;
```

It works properly on desktop. how could I solve this problem?

This problem appears in functional components too.

What I've tryed:

- adding cursor: pointer
- changing onClick to onPointerDown
- changing onClick to onTouchStart

None of them worked, any ideas?

---

### Edit

There are 3 different shortcodes for wordpress, 2 buttons (increment, and decrement) and a counter, they should work together:
increment and decrement buttons (in the original question above) write into localstorage:

```
increment(eventid, invoiceitemid, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const invoiceItems = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem(`invoiceItems${eventid}`) ?? "null"
    );
    if (!invoiceItems[invoiceitemid]) {
      invoiceItems[invoiceitemid] = 1;
    } else {
      invoiceItems[invoiceitemid] += 1;
    }
    localStorage.setItem(
      `invoiceItems${eventid}`,
      JSON.stringify(invoiceItems)
    );
  }
```

And there is a counter what should read the localstorage:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    const getCounterData = setInterval(() => {
      let invoiceItems = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem(`invoiceItems${props.eventid}`)
      );
      if (counter !== invoiceItems[props.invoiceitemid]) {
        setCounter(invoiceItems[props.invoiceitemid]);
      }
    }, 200);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(getCounterData);
    };
  });

  return (
    <span
      id={"co" + props.invoiceitemid}
      className={"counter" + props.eventid}
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        textAlign: "center",
        border: "none",
        justifyContent: "center",
        color: props.buttonTextColor,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
      }}
      counter={counter}
    >
      {counter}
    </span>
  );
```

This works properly on desktop:
[image]

Comment: Can you describe in better detail what exactly isn't working? Have you confirmed that the button isn't being clicked, or is it that the `increment` function isn't invoked as expected? Or is there something else you done to verify/validate on mobile? Can you add debugging details?

Comment: Added some more details to the question and a gif for the expected behavior.